# PGP encryption and decryption with BouncyCastle v1.8.6

Tags: encryption, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption, pgp, openpgp

Hello PGP and encryption gurus,

I'm trying to implement my own PGP component in one of my project using BouncyCastle framework v1.8.6.
I'm getting this output:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE-----
Version: BCPG C# v1.8.6.0
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=HT2J
-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

using this implementation:

```cs
public void EncryptAndSign() {
    _CompressionAlgorithm = CompressionAlgorithmTag.Uncompressed;
    _SymmetricKeyAlgorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.TripleDes;
    _PgpSignatureType = PgpSignature.CanonicalTextDocument;
    _FileType = PGPFileType.Binary;
    _HashAlgorithmTag = HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1;

    string
    var = "Hello this me first PGP Encrypt";

    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(var);

    PgpLiteralDataGenerator pgpLiteralDataGenerator = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();
    PgpEncryptedDataGenerator encryptedDataGenerator = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(_SymmetricKeyAlgorithm, false, new SecureRandom());
    encryptedDataGenerator.AddMethod(m_encryptionKeys.PublicKey);

    using(var sout = new MemoryStream()) {
        using(var armoredOut = new ArmoredOutputStream(sout)) {
            using(var clearOut = new MemoryStream()) {

                PublicKeyAlgorithmTag tag = m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.Algorithm;
                PgpSignatureGenerator pgpSignatureGenerator = new PgpSignatureGenerator(tag, _HashAlgorithmTag);
                pgpSignatureGenerator.InitSign(_PgpSignatureType, m_encryptionKeys.PrivateKey);
                foreach(string userId in m_encryptionKeys.SecretKey.PublicKey.GetUserIds()) {
                    PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator subPacketGenerator = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
                    subPacketGenerator.SetSignerUserId(false, userId);
                    pgpSignatureGenerator.SetHashedSubpackets(subPacketGenerator.Generate());
                    // Just the first one!
                    break;
                }

                pgpSignatureGenerator.GenerateOnePassVersion(false).Encode(clearOut);

                using(var literalOut = pgpLiteralDataGenerator.Open(clearOut, PgpLiteralData.Text, "", data.Length, DateTime.Now)) {
                    literalOut.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                    pgpSignatureGenerator.Update(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                pgpSignatureGenerator.Generate().Encode(clearOut);

                var clearData = clearOut.ToArray();

                using(var encryptOut = encryptedDataGenerator.Open(armoredOut, clearData.Length)) {
                    encryptOut.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
                }
            }
        }

        var d = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(sout.ToArray());
        File.WriteAllText(@"D:\pgp\MyTestEncrypt.txt", d);
    }
}
```

When I try to decrypt the above stated PGP message, I get this error:

```
attempt to process message to long for cipher
```

There is no innerException it's null. But there is this stacktrace:

```
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.BufferedAsymmetricBlockCipher.ProcessBytes(Byte[] input, Int32 inOff, Int32 length)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData.RecoverSessionData(PgpPrivateKey privKey)
   at Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp.PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData.GetDataStream(PgpPrivateKey privKey)
   at PGPEncryption.PGPDecrypt.decrypt(Stream input, String outputpath) in C:\Users\test\source\repos\ConsoleApp2\ConsoleApp2\PGPDecrypt.cs:line 50
e.Source
BouncyCastle.Crypto
```

Decrypt implementation:

```cs
public void decrypt(Stream input, string outputpath) {

    try {
        using(FileStream fsEncryptedFile = File.Open(@"D:\pgp\MyTestEncrypt.txt", FileMode.Open)) {
            using(Stream decoderStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(fsEncryptedFile)) {
                PgpObjectFactory factory = new PgpObjectFactory(decoderStream);
                PgpObject obj = factory.NextPgpObject();
                if (! (obj is PgpEncryptedDataList)) {
                    obj = factory.NextPgpObject(); // first object might be a PGP marker packet
                }
                PgpEncryptedDataList edl = obj as PgpEncryptedDataList;

                foreach(PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData data in edl.GetEncryptedDataObjects()) {
                    PgpPrivateKey privateKey = GetPrivateKey(@"D:\pgp\SecyretKey\openpgp_test.asc");

                    PgpObjectFactory plainFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(data.GetDataStream(pgpKeys.PrivateKey));
                    PgpObject message = plainFactory.NextPgpObject();
                    if (message is PgpCompressedData) {
                        message = new PgpObjectFactory(((PgpCompressedData) message).GetDataStream()).NextPgpObject();
                    }
                    if (message is PgpLiteralData) {
                        PgpLiteralData ld = (PgpLiteralData) message;
                        using(FileStream outStream = File.Create(@"D:\pgp\MessageOut_Decrypt.txt")) {
                            Stream inStream = ld.GetInputStream();
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[0x100000];
                            int count = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            while (count > 0) {
                                outStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                                count = inStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                            outStream.Close();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Unknown type of message in PGP file: {0}", message.GetType().FullName);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How do I remove the "Version" part in the genereted PGP message?
2. Why is i'm getting the error message when try to decrypt the message?

Comment: That's not the totality of the error message you get. Instead, you get an exception with an exception stack trace that usually includes important information such as the line causing the exception. At least provide that much information.

Comment: Hi James, there is no innerException that object is null, but i get a stacktrace which I have updated in description.

Comment: Ok. Now if I'm reading the stacktrace correctly, the exception occurs at line 50 of your code. Can you please tell us which line is line 50?

Comment: Hi, Line 50 is this: PgpObjectFactory plainFactory = new PgpObjectFactory(data.GetDataStream(pgpKeys.PrivateKey)); in the decrypt implementation